Praying for too many people?
I have a list of people that I daven for, for many different things (shidduch, health, for them to lachzor betshuva, etc)  It seems this list became too long though and I'm not able to focus on each person during a minyan. Is there any other way to pray for each person (like tehilim maybe?) And will it be as effective as praying for them during shemonah esrei? I'm willing to take as much time as it takes for the sake of each and every one of them.

"I'm not able to focus on each person during a minyan” I don't understand how this matches with your last sentence

Why do you think "Oh God, please heal all people on this list" won't work? Moses said "Please heal her" so God presumably knew who Moses referred to, why not a list? We do pray for "all IDF soldiers", "all ministers", or "all sick Jews", why not "all people on this list"?

@AlBerko "I pray for all the things I should pray for"

@DoubleAA I think, "I pray" will suffice. You just check in, God knows the rest.

@AlBerko I think you'd need a direct object, but anyway, this is clearly not what Moshe did nor what Chazal enacted we do.

@DoubleAA Follow-up https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/144844/personal-requests-in-prayers-according-to-rambam

Related: Davening for multiple things; Praying for too much.

@DoubleAA i meant that the minyan goes by too fast for me to able to daven for them all, but im willing to sacrifice extra free time for them otherwise.

I once heard, from Rav Paysach Krohn שליט"א, that in such a case you should every day just concentrate on a few of them, and the next day on a few others

This is a good answer. Thank you very much
