Optional personal requests in prayers according to Rambam
Following "Praying-for-too-many-people".
In my understanding, Rambam had a peculiar and somewhat unorthodox view of God's immutability and inability to be influenced by our Earthly prayers. This aligns with the Gemmora that states, that the only choice humans have is to be pious or wicked, nothing from physical reality.
Therefore, he saw the prayers as meditations, aimed at bettering ourselves, our knowledge of God, our beliefs in final salvation, seeking guidance and wisdom, cultivating humility and modesty, promoting moral growth and self-reflection, maintaining a connection with God, unifying the community, and more. (I might have a wrong understanding of Rambam though).
The Gemmorah in Brochos concludes that one can add personal requests in the middle Brochos. And our personal requests, do focus mostly on physical wellbeing and prosperity.
From Rambam's view, what's the purpose of optional personal requests, and, since God can't be influenced, what intentions should a person have while reciting those requests in prayer?

How are personal requests any different from the rest of prayer in this regard? Why would they require a different explanation than that which the Rambam gave for prayer in general?

@QwertyCTRL. IIRC, Rambam held that the prayer is a sort of fixed-wording meditation, that does not influence God's will or action. If you know it doesn't work, why pray for people?

You mean, why pray for other people, or why pray for yourself? If the former, please edit the question to clarify. If the latter—please explain how that answers my first comment.

@QwertyCTRL. IMU, in Rambam's view you don't pray for yourself, like cure me, or make me rich, but you recite a meditation to become a better man in general, sort like Buddhist ruminations. I think I outlined it pretty clearly in the question. Prayers don't influence God or His way of running the world. So to your question it's neither.

Rambam explains that each request in the Tefillah is in order to make us realize that we are dependent on Hashem in every aspect of our lives. I still don’t see the problem here.

@QwertyCTRL. Exactly, so by reciting Rafaenu, you meditate on "our dependence" on God in matters of health, but praying for oneself or the recital of names is knowingly ineffective. Hence the question - why add personal prayers?

You mean the optional personal prayers that can be inserted in certain places?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't understand a question based on "IIRC". As usual, I'd like to request that you ask about the thing that you are assuming rather than "thinking past the sale" https://www.perplexity.ai/search/scott-adams-asking-beyond-the-fJJgxrttQECPvQGTORHukQ

@MichoelR "404 Page Not Found". I changed IIRC, to IMU.

This seems to be a similar question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29109/if-hashem-doesnt-change-how-does-prayer-work See my answer there where I object to that question too.

@MichoelR Not exactly. According to Rambam prayer as a personal meditation, reciting religious mantras, is effective. I focused specifically on personal requests that imply to be influencing God's choices.
