Why specify individuals in a mi sheberach?
The standard template for a "mi sheberach" always ends with something along the lines of, "V'et kol khal hakadosh hazeh".
That being the case, why do Olim laTorah (and gabbaim) insist on singling out individual members of the community, such as the Rabbi, Ba'al Koreh, friends of the Oleh etc.? Does the blessing have a greater effect if the individual receiving it is directly identified?

Everyone likes hearing their name

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/144766/praying-for-too-many-people#comment484179_144766
